# Minumum tin which to create cylinder that has $1 L$ volume

Tags: geometry, volume

What is the minumum $cm^2$ tin which you need to create $1L$ closed cylinder

Any hint?

it is $\pi r^2h=1$

$2\pi r^2+2\pi rh =2(\frac {r+h}{hr})$

edit:

$h=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$

$f(r)=2\pi r^2+2\pi r\frac{1}{\pi r^2}=2\pi r^2+\frac{2}{r}$

$f'(r)=0 \rightarrow 4\pi r=\frac{2}{r^2}$

$r= {\dfrac  {1} {\sqrt[3]{2\pi} }}$

$f(r)=2\pi{\dfrac  {1} {\sqrt[3]{4\pi^2} }}+ 2\sqrt[3]{2\pi} $

$f(r)=\sqrt[3]{2\pi}+  2\sqrt[3]{2\pi}= 3\sqrt[3]{2\pi}$

This answer isnt in the options. Can u tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: The first equation gives you a relation: $h = 1/(\pi r^2)$. Feed this into the formula for the surface area to get surface area as a function of $r$. Do you know how to calculate the minima of this function?

Comment: thank you. $r=\dfrac {1} {\sqrt [3] {2\pi }}$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 could you check my edit? options are like  $200\dfrac {\left( 2\pi +1\right) } {\sqrt [3] {4\pi ^{2}}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have Calculated $\displaystyle f(r) = 2\pi r^2+\frac{2}{r}\;,$ Here $\bf{r(radius)>0}$

So Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M\;,}$ We get $\displaystyle \frac{\left[2\pi r^2+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}\right]}{3}\geq \left(2\pi r^2\cdot \frac{1}{r}\cdot \frac{1}{r}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

So we get $\displaystyle2\pi r^2+ \frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r}\geq 3\cdot \left(2\pi \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

And equality hold when $\displaystyle 2\pi r^2 = \frac{1}{r}\Rightarrow r= \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

So Minimum Surface area $\displaystyle f(r)$ occur at $\displaystyle  r= \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

So we get $\displaystyle S \left[\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right] = 2\pi \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{2}{ \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} = \left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+2\cdot \left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 3\cdot \left(2\pi\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

May be Option Given is Wrong.

Comment: I see. may it be about m2 - cm2 conversion ?